# Google checkout integration with asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-checkout

Im looking for the way to do the integration of my shopping cart with a payment way. I want to do with *Google Checkout* and I'm using *Asp.net MVC4 C#*.

**Any tutorial or idea for implement that?**

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant Google Wallet as the Google Checkout API has been deprecated since November 2013:

http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2013/05/an-update-to-google-checkout-for.html

If you are selling digital goods you may consider the [Google Wallet for digital goods API](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/). A C# sample implementation can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/samples#iap-cs

Comment: Thanks Mihai, I knew that, it was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Just for information of new developers who want to integrate **Google Wallet** "Google wallet is going to be retired March 2, 2015".

They write "This only applies to web developers accepting payments for digital goods on their own websites using the Google Wallet for digital goods API". Visit the following link for further details

https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/6107573?hl=en